# is there a 64-bit msdasql for windows 7?

Tags: odbc

I am using Windows 7 (x64bit) Ultimate.

I have both ODBC32 and ODBC64 Managers that I can access via Start.
The default appears to be the ODBC64.

However I do not see MSDASQL -Microsoft OLEDB for ODBC listed.

I wonder if it exists. I see some references to 64Bit MSDASQL for Windows Server 2003.
The IBM 64bit for ODBC seems to work (I heard) but not tried.
Now I would like to know if any one knows the link for 64-bit MSDASQL for Windows 7. Microsoft seems to have deprecated MSDASQL and I am not sure of the status of this story.

These issues came up while setting up a linked server in SQL Server 2012 for SQL (SAP) SqlAnywhere server.

Comment: This works for me http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how I missed. This link allows you to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
The details of this indicates both ODBC and OLEDB as copied from the Microsoft Web Site:
"This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text files is also supported. **ODBC and OLEDB** drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats. "

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Oh the fun of having to connect to a dbase program in 2015 and wanting to do it from within a 64bit program. Thank you

Comment: When downloading at the MS site, end users have the option of a 32 or 64bit. Which one should they choose? (I have a 64bit Win7)

Answer (score 0):

There is no MSDASQL x64 bit for Windows 7. There is one for Windows Server 2003. I finally was able to create a linked server in SQL Server 2012 Express using the SAOLEDB.16 from Sybase/SAP.

Although I replied myself that there is no MSDASQL(x64)based on some 'deprecated items' information I am still looking at it.

Here is a link to the same question on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c715023-4322-4bc6-a2c8-64a873f87e46/can-someone-confirm-the-architecture-of-this-file-preferably-microsoft-guys?forum=sqldatabaseengine#db5ed4e2-2391-4062-b34d-1f1b11431e1e