# Query MYSQL Database From MSSQL Windows10

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-10, msdasql

I have a MYSQL database I would like to link my MSSQL database to.

Previously I had this system working, utilising the MSDASQL Linked Server Provider, and creating an ODBC datasource using the latest MYSQL odbc driver.

Since my Windows 10 Upgrade this has stopped working. It is fortunately still working on a windows 2008 server.

The ODBC Datasource test connection is also still operational. When testing the connection within sql management studio, it fails with Exception "Unable to initalise MSDASQL Provider, No specific Information was given".

The ODBC Datasource works within Microsoft Access 2010.

From what I understand the MSDASQL provider is now deprecated? What other provider should I be using?

Comment: any luck here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24601508

Comment: nope, didn't work. Managed to get it working on an SQL 2014 server instance on windows 10. The 2012 instance still doesn't work although it may be possible to update the MSDASQL provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem. I managed to get it working with an SQL 2014 instance. So it seems like the linked server provider for MSDASQL in 2012 and earlier is not compatible with windows 10 ODBC.

Are you able to try it on an SQL 2014 instance? Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Okay. I just set this up on a 2014 instance and it is indeed working fine! Thanks! I wonder if there is an update for pre-2014 to get it working? In any case my problem is solved as I can easily migrate my database across.

Comment: Just to add to this - it seems like the MSDASQL is still the linked server provider that is in use by the linked server instance. Might be possible to update the MSDASQL 2012 provider.