# How to create user-dsn with correct driver for w10 64bit ms-access odbc

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, 64-bit, dbase

I'm following the book "Access 2016 Programming By Example With vba, xml and ASP. The book teaches me VBA, I'm still a noob. This chapter covers the basics of setting up a user-dns. This user-dns will be user by ms-access vba to connect via this user-dns to a .dbf-file. I'm on Windows 10 64bit with office 2016 64 bit. The code in the book results in an error: 'the driver architecture and the application do not align with the DNS'. Google nor the book provide a suitable solution. I'm thinking it has something to do with the bit versions of Windows or Office. Please advice.

The book mentions the code below, and describes to open configuration screen, odbc, user dns, select "Microsoft dBase driver (*.dbf) name it "MyDbaseFile" and finish.

Difference with book and Windows 10 is that there are two windows for ODBC settings, one 32bit and one 64bit. Only within the 32bit window, I can find the described driver name. In the 64bit window I cannot find it. The book describes only one window so I think that's based on W7 or something else.

Total code from the book:

```
Sub Open_AndRead_dBaseFile()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=MyDbaseFile;"

    Debug.Print conn.ConnectionString

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open "CUSTOMER.dbf", conn

    Do Until rst.EOF
        Debug.Print rst.Fields(1).Value
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Expecting to show in immidiate window in VBA editor the content of customer.dbf. Error message rises as mentioned earlier, this rises with the code line:

```
conn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=MyDbaseFile;"
```

Comment: `In the 64bit window I cannot find it` - correct, and you can only use the ones you can see in the 64-bit window. `The book describes only one window so I think that's based on W7` - no, the book assumes you are using 32-bit Office. If you want to use the providers from the 32-bit window, you have to switch to 32-bit Office (Windows bitness does not matter). Or try finding and installing 64-bit versions of providers you are interested in, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24601508/11683.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled office 32 bit, works like a charm now.